# opengl mapped array buffer is always too small

Tags: arrays, opengl

I am using vertex array objects in my opengl application. When I was testing it small numbers of vertices, mapping the array buffer was no problem. Then I tried allocating a bigger buffer thus :

```
    unsigned int vaoToStore, vboToStore[2];
    glGenVertexArrays ( 1, &vaoToStore );
    glBindVertexArray ( vaoToStore );

    glGenBuffers ( 2, vboToStore );
    glBindBuffer ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboToStore[0] );

    glBufferData ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                   30000,
                   NULL,
                   GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW );

    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( kAttribPositionLoc );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( kAttribColorLoc );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( kAttribTexcoordLoc );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( kAttribMaskIndex );

    glVertexAttribPointer ( kAttribPositionLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 10 * sizeof ( float ), 0 );
    glVertexAttribPointer ( kAttribColorLoc, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 10 * sizeof ( float ), ( void* ) ( 3*sizeof ( float ) ) );
    glVertexAttribPointer ( kAttribTexcoordLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 10 * sizeof ( float ), ( void* ) ( 7*sizeof ( float ) ) );
    glVertexAttribPointer ( kAttribMaskIndex, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 10 * sizeof ( float ), ( void* ) ( 9*sizeof ( float ) ) );

    glBindBuffer ( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboToStore[1] );

    glBufferData ( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                   1000 * sizeof ( unsigned int ),
                   NULL,
                   GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW );
```

Then when mapping with glMapBufferRange, the element array would work fine, but the attributes array would always return null unless I map only a size of 100 or less...
Is that the normal behaviour? I scoured google and the opengl references but they all seem to suggest that it should be possible.

**mapping code as requested**

```
float *vertAttribs = reinterpret_cast<float*> ( glMapBufferRange( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 30000, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT ) );

    unsigned int *elements = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*> ( glMapBufferRange ( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 1000 * sizeof ( unsigned int ), GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT ) );
```

Now, as I said, mapping the elements buffer like this worked, whereas even if I change the size from 30000 to (sizeof(float)*1000) the attributes array throws INVALID_VALUE on mapping...

Comment: Please show the mapping code also. It is totally unclear whatr you are mapping, and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK!! Figured it out : I was not aware GL_ARRAY_BUFFER binding was not part of the VAO's state...so I was binding the VAO and thought it meant having bound the array buffer too. Noob mistake I believe, which explains why the display of the other VAO was all screwed up, and it was smaller too, which explained the limited mapping range.